# Uploading photos from iPhone to iCloud Photos, using iOS 14 - is it working / what is the status?

Tags: ios, icloud

My iPhone has thousands of photos. I'd like to store them in [iCloud Photos](https://www.apple.com/uk/icloud/), to help me migrate to a new iPhone with less storage.

I've set it up, following the [section in the iPhone User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph961b96c4d/ios) and the [Set up and use iCloud Photos support document](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204264).

Looking at my photos in a web browser at [icloud.com/photos](https://www.icloud.com/photos/), it seems my iPhone has only uploaded some of my photos. I can only see about my last 6 months of photos there, but I have many more on my phone.

The documentation I've linked to above is extremely minimal for a complicated feature like this, and doesn't seem to help.

How can I tell the status of the iCloud Photos upload process on my iOS 14 iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

On your iPhone, in the Photos app, at the bottom, select the Library tab. Then select All Photos.

Then **swipe upwards**.  This should reveal some hidden information about the status of the iCloud Photos upload, which I've highlighted with a red box in this screenshot:

[image: Status, revealed after swiping up]

Here, this uncovers that the iPhone has paused the upload, to save battery power. I'm not sure if it warns you about this - perhaps it doesn't, or do you eg have a kid that might have dismissed an alert without telling you?

If you press the blue Resume "button" / link, it'll continue uploading.

The [iCloud Photos support document](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204264) does have a hint about this in the (literally) small print. Emphasis is mine:

> Your collection is uploaded to iCloud each time your device connects to Wi-Fi **and your battery is charged**. When you have iOS 11 or later, your library can be updated over mobile data also.

If you've spent a long time trying to figure this out before finding this information, don't blame yourself. In my opinion, this is an example of poor design from Apple - this feature has low [discoverability](https://uxdesign.cc/the-a-to-z-of-ux-d-is-for-discoverability-a-15-point-list-to-ensuring-users-find-what-they-need-8659416eec41).